# How do I put my index.html in the same folder as my other .html files on github?

Tags: html, css, github

So I just started web development an began building my portfolio. Although most of my content is on the same page and most links redirect to different websites, I do have one link that redirects to a different page of my website. So the content changes but the navigation bar is still there.

However, the files can't be found when I load my website. Can someone clearly tell me how to put all my files in the same folder on Github? I believe you have to redirect the index.html into a new folder with the other HTML files. What exact info should I put in my original index.html file (outside of folder) so it redirects correctly? And is there anything I need to do with .css?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple JS call

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.location.href = 'path/to/your/page.html';
</script>
```

This can be the only content inside your new index.html but it is required to have an index page for the web client to recognize.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer! Quite new to github and web development.

Comment: Alright. Be sure to select an answer once it has been resolved